Getting issue while installing Sitecore 10.4 On Premises
I am trying to install Sitecore 10.4 via Installation Assistant for XP Single and getting the following issue while installing the prerequisites.

Authenticode issuer 'CN="Sitecore USA, Inc.", OU=IT, O="Sitecore USA, Inc.", L=San 
Francisco, S=California, C=US' of the new module 'SitecoreInstallFramework' with 
version '2.4.0' from root certificate authority 'CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, 
OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US' is not matching with the authenticode issuer 
'CN="Sitecore USA, Inc.", O="Sitecore USA, Inc.", L=Sausalito, S=ca, C=US' of the 
previously-installed module 'SitecoreInstallFramework' with version '2.3.0' from root 
certificate authority 'CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert 
Inc, C=US'. If you still want to install or update, use -SkipPublisherCheck parameter.

Did anyone see this issue while installing?

Thanks @Sreekrishnan for your answer. Yes this was resolved by adding the parameter -SkipPublisherCheck while installing the SIF 2.4.0
While checking the FAQs of SIF 2.4.0 I found the commands to manually install it.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-powershell-public-nuget-feed-faq.html
I manually installed the SIF 2.4.0 using this command.
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.4.0 -force -SkipPublisherCheck

After that, I was able to resolve this error.
Thanks

The error message suggests a conflict between versions of the Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF). Let's check which versions are currently installed on your machine to diagnose the issue.
Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework –ListAvailable

To manually install SIF 2.4.0 with the SkipPublisherCheck flag, run this PowerShell command
Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework -SkipPublisherCheck -Force

By this the installation should proceed without issues, and the newly installed SIF version will also be included in the list
Now, re-run the SIA prerequisites and the prerequisites installation should be successful.
This is also mentioned in the blog : https://insightswithvishalkhera.wordpress.com/2024/04/30/install-sitecore-xp-10-4-using-sitecore-install-assistantt/

I faced the same issue but manually installing the 2.4.0 module using the command in other answers didn't fix that error. I also ran the uninstall module command which removed the 2.4.0 and 2.3.0 but didn't remove older versions such as 1.2.0.
To fix it I had to manually remove (or rename) the SIF module folders from

C:\Users[user]\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

After that, the install assistant ran smoothly.
